# What should be the data type for this?

Tags: database

I am creating a table which will have a field "Website" in my database. What should I set it as, "INT", Varchar" or what and why?

Thank You

I plan to put website URL's in it.

Comment: What do you plan to store in it?

Comment: What are you going to put in it?

Comment: You expect to be able to store a URL in an Int column?

Comment: Take some time to read this: http://cplus.about.com/od/introductiontoprogramming/p/database.htm http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/mssql_datatypes.htm . From the way it looks, you have a very poor understanding what a database really is. BoltClock edited the tags because it has nothing to do with HTML, or any other languages besides SQL. The first article will also show you what are RDBMS. The second article will show you a list of data types used in MSSQL, although you will find most of them in most of contemporary RDBMS. It's not an answer, just an advice. That's why it's in a comment

Answer (score 2):

What are you planning on storing in this field? Please give an example of the data.

I'll assume you mean a URL, such as "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104609/what-should-be-the-data-type-for-this".

In most databases, such as MySQL or Postgres, the proper type for this would indeed be varchar.

For instance, see MySQL's string type reference. It will explain the differences between char, varchar, text and blob. Namely, that varchar is more efficient and easier to work with than char for the most common uses, because char pads each entry with trailing spaces to fit the maximum length.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

Answer (score 0):

You should select Varchar to store website URL in that field